# Laravel - Delete and save in one query

Tags: laravel

In my app users can vote on submissions.

I first run a delete query for that submission to prevent any duplicate votes, then I save the vote:

```
 SubmissionVote::where('submission_id', $submission->id)->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->delete();

 $submissionVote = new SubmissionVote;
 $submissionVote->submission_id = $submission->id;
 $submissionVote->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
 $submissionVote->vote = $vote;
 $submissionVote->save();
```

Would it be possible to write this as one query to minimize overall database queries?
Or perhaps there's a way in the table migration to make it so that every `submission_id` can only have unique `user_id`s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it perhaps.

```
Schema::create('submission_votes', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->unique([
    'submission_id',
    'user_id',
  ]);
});
```

And, update existing model:

```
SubmissionVote::query()->updateOrInsert(
  ['user_id' => Auth::user()->id, 'submission_id' => $submission->id], 
  ['vote' => $vote]
);
```

Comment: Cool! I didn't know about updateOrInsert. But what's the point of adding unique to submission_id and user_id in the migration and also using updateOrInsert?

Comment: Just to avoid errors - if you try to insert duplicate - eloquent throw exception. With updateOrInsert - just updated. Btw, eloquent construction in another answer from @Flame is better than my

Answer (score 1):

You could do this in a neater way like so:

Create a proper relation on the User model:

```php
// models/User.php
public function submissionVote()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(SubmissionVote::class);
}
```

then simply use this single statement in your controller:

```php
Auth::user()->submissionVote()->updateOrCreate([
    'vote' => $vote,
]);
```

This automatically updates the current user's submission OR creates a new one if it doesnt exist yet. Note that you have to use `->submissionVote()` (query instance) vs `->submissionVote` (model instance) so that you can use the query functions like `updateOrCreate()`. There are others available like `firstOrCreate()` or `firstOrNew()` which do slightly different things but are extremely handy shortcuts.

See https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#upserts for more information.